# sending ajax data directly to attribute

Tags: ajax, jquery

Using Jquery AJAX to get a value from a PHP script.

This line works fine:

```
$.post('get_img.php',function(data){$("#result").append(data)});
```

This line does not:

```
$.post('get_img.php',function(data){$("div:hidden:first").css('background-image','url(data)')});
```

How can I get the data returned from the ajax call to go directly to the url value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `data` is a variable, if you want to use its value then it should be concatenated to the string.

```
$.post('get_img.php', function(data){
        $("div:hidden:first")
        .css('background-image','url(' + data + ')')
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$.post('get_img.php', function(data) {
    $("div:hidden:first").css('background-image','url(' + data + ')')
});
```

The variable `data` was being passed as a string.